# Any receiver for sent SMS messages?

Tags: android

Hi we get an event when new sms come in android but can we get any event when user send a messages, in short is there any receiver to track sending sms as we track incoming sms.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a broadcast intent for outgoing SMS messages unfortunately.

The best you can do (if you have to!) is poll the SMS content provider (`content://sms/sent`) periodically and remember which messages you see.

Answer (score 0):

U can also use ContentObserver listening on the content://sms, then the onChange will be invoked when the sms database changed.